# How can I write query to get the following output in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle

## Table Format and Data

[image]

## Requirement.

Snapshot of the count of work with status "NEW" for each hour.

Required output for the day 04/11/2014(between 04/11/2014 00:00:01 and 04/11/2014 23:59:59) for status "NEW"

## Output (Count of work with status new for each hour)

[image]

Is it possible to get the output with a single query? It will be highly appreciated if you paste the query.

I tried to take the count for each hour with group by for the hour. But, it doesn't count the between range. Also tried to executing multiple queries by looping in java. I don't prefer the last method. (looping in java). I wanted to know is it possible to with single execution of single mysql query.

Comment: Posted following details.                                  I tried to take the count for each hour with group by for the hour. But, it doesn't count the between range. Also tried to executing multiple queries by looping in java. I don't prefer the last method. (looping in java). I wanted to know is it possible to with single execution of single mysql query. Please share if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `GROUP BY` that formats the date into something that is unique per hour, like this:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y%m%d%H');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. It won't consider the hours between the start and end time.